# AWS User Pool Setup (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS Cognito User Pools to add login/signup functionality for my swift iOS app. I have set up my xcworkspace with Cocoapods. In my App Delegate I have set up my Credentials Provider and Service Configuration seen below.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId)

    let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration

    return true
}
```

but when i try to set up the user pool configuration with:

```
let configurationUserPool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: "###", clientSecret: "#########", poolId: "###")
```

i get a compilation error of "use of unresolved identifier AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration", which i dont understand because i have imported AWSCore and AWSCognito

any help or insight would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: Fixed this by installing and importing AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

Comment: How did you assigned configurationUserPool? I'm getting Cannot assign  value of type 'AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration' to type 'AWSServiceConfiguration'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

Must also be added to the project and imported in your AppDelegate class in order for that method to be accessible.